# Canvas apparently running multiple threads

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I've got this code whose purpose is to run the classic Nokia snake. The code itself works as expected, but my problem is when you call the main function again (to restart the game), then the canvas will produce 2 snakes, on a third loop, 4, on a fourth, 8 and so forth. Using only jQuery and JS, [here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y72njfc1/). Play lose once, reload, see the duplicates.

Here's the code that loads the game:

```
 function snakeLoad() {
            loadSnake();
            $(document).on('click', '#startSnake', function () {
                $(this).remove();
                startSnake();
            });

            function loadSnake() {
                //start button
                $('main').append('<div id="snake"><button id="startSnake">Click to start</button><canvas id="snakeCanvas" height="380" width="380">Get a modern browser</canvas><div>');
            }
            ;
```

And this is the function that actually initialized the thing:

```
function startSnake() {
                //create grid
                var snakeCanvas = document.getElementById("snakeCanvas");
                var ctx = snakeCanvas.getContext("2d");

                //Global game vars init
                var randomSeed = function (min, max) {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                };
                var snakeLength = 1;
                var snakePositions = [{x: randomSeed(14, 25) * 10, y: randomSeed(14, 25) * 10}];
                var foodPosition = {x: randomSeed(25, 35) * 10, y: randomSeed(25, 35) * 10};
                var snakeDirection = ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'][randomSeed(0, 3)];
                var i = 0;

                console.log(snakePositions, foodPosition, snakeDirection);

//Draw initial position
//Snake
                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
                ctx.fillRect(snakePositions[0].x, snakePositions[0].y, 10, 10);
//Food
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fillRect(foodPosition.x, foodPosition.y, 10, 10);
```

Then the main in-game loop with the lose conditions:

```
var moveSnake = setInterval(function () {
 //... doing its thing
//On losing:
 clearInterval(moveSnake);
return endSnake();
```

And this is the end game script and the action for the restart button:

```
function endSnake() {
$('#snake').remove();
$('main').html('<br/><input class="endGamer" id="playSnakeAgain" type="button" value="Play&#x00A;Snake&#x00A;Again" data-app="snake">');
            }
 $(document).on('click', '#playSnakeAgain', function (e) {
 $('main').empty();
 snakeLoad();
            });
```

The problem is that when snakeLoad is called a second time, the part of the code where the initial positions are runs multiple times, more with every rerun. There is no loop of any sort there, any idea why is it exponentially adding more loops?

Thanks for your help, it's been driving me nuts for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you're calling `snakeLoad`, you're adding an additional `click` handler to the document:

```
$(document).on('click',....
```

So when you do click on the `#startSnake` button added in `loadSnake`, there are multiple event handlers running, each calling `startSnake()`.  Instead, just register that event handler once, outside of `snakeLoad`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#startSnake', function () {
    $(this).remove();
    startSnake();
});

function loadSnake() {
    //start button
    $('main').append('<div id="snake"><button id="startSnake">Click to start</button><canvas id="snakeCanvas" height="380" width="380">Get a modern browser</canvas><div>');
}

function snakeLoad() {
    loadSnake();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@James Thorpe - Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

In the end I just added:
    $(document).off('click', '#startSnake');
    $(document).off('click', '#playSnakeAgain');

After each binding and it's now working as expected. Hope this helps others with similar issues.